# Getting Error Message While Annotate the Text in Intent Training Phrases

Tags: dialogflow-es

Getting Rangy is undifined error when trying to annotate the text in training phrase in dialogflow intent. Annotation is not Working in Dialogflow.Entity Mapping in Not Working in Training Phrases in Dialogflow intent

[For Reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hozw6.png)

Comment: Please refer to [this answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77664627/22925578)