# Wont highlight entities

Tags: dialogflow-es

I cant annotate intents any more.

Tried to highlight an entity. It didn't.

I made a video of above of the issue https://www.loom.com/share/7d05b4231dc4495ea4650842ca0dc047

Comment: [Dialogflow ES: Training phrase Error: rangy is not define](https://www.googlecloudcommunity.com/gc/AI-ML/Dialogflow-ES-Training-phrase-Error-rangy-is-not-define/m-p/681801). It doesn't seem to have been resolved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a [JavaScript library issue](https://www.googlecloudcommunity.com/gc/AI-ML/Dialogflow-ES-Training-phrase-Error-rangy-is-not-define/m-p/681801) and you can try the following workaround.

Go to your browser's developer console and load the library [rangy](https://www.npmjs.com/package/rangy)

```js
// Rangy Core
var scriptCore = document.createElement('script');
scriptCore.src = 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rangy/1.3.1/rangy-core.min.js';
document.head.appendChild(scriptCore);

// Rangy ClassApplier
var scriptClassApplier = document.createElement('script');
scriptClassApplier.src = 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rangy/1.3.1/rangy-classapplier.min.js';
document.head.appendChild(scriptClassApplier);

// Rangy TextRange
var scriptTextRange = document.createElement('script');
scriptTextRange.src = 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rangy/1.3.1/rangy-textrange.min.js';
document.head.appendChild(scriptTextRange);

// check load
scriptTextRange.onload = function() {
    console.log('Rangy library loaded successfully.');
};
```

[image: Dialogflow ES Entity highlight workaround]

Comment: Working now thanks