# Unable to assign an entity to a selected word in Dialogflow

Tags: dialogflow-es

[image]

I tried assigning a system entity `@sys.number`, but even after selecting, no popup window is getting visible.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77664627/22925578